# Extrapolation and linear splines

Tags: spline

Can you use a linear spline for extrapolation? Say you have data
(6,1.04),(7,1.71),(9,3.28),(10,4.08); and you wanted to evaluate at x=17. I thought that extrapolating using linear splines was a bad idea--is that true?

Comment: I assume that you mean linear extrapolation if you leave your interpolation interval. What makes you think that this is a bad idea? Use whatever fits best your actual problem. It is only a bad idea if the data from the last interplation interval is probably bad (e.g., noisy). In that case you should use approximation anyway and extrapolate the approximation.

Comment: Okay, so in this case it should be f(x)=3.28+0.8(x-9), in which case f(17)=9.68 ? I thought it may be a bad idea since the interpolation polynomial wasn't for that data point, but since the last interval doesn't have noisy data it should work?

Comment: When you have to extrapolate it means that you need an approximation at a point where you do not have data. Use as much problem relevant information as you get to obtain a good approximation there! Just an example: If you know that the signal you are approximating is limited it is better to use constant extrapolation. If you do not know anything maybe you are good with linear extrapolation.

Comment: I understand the concept of extrapolation, I guess what I am getting confused on is how else I should think about solving this problem, other than using the interpolation interval for x between 9 and 10, since I don't know anything else other than those 4 data points. Say, if I calculate the other interpolation intervals, how can I use that information to obtain a better approximation than just using the last interpolation interval? Thanks for the help, by the way.